# Add prefix or suffix to filename while streaming the file using GET gateway

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I want to add the temporary prefix or suffix while streaming the file from a remote directory using SFTP.

I have tried to add temporaryFileSuffix to outboundGateway while streaming the file but it is not adding any suffix later I checked it is documented that 
"Set the temporary suffix to use when transferring files to the remote system."

```
.handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), GET, "payload.remoteDirectory + payload.filename").options(STREAM).temporaryFileSuffix("_reading"))
```

Do I need to Rename the file using Rename gateway or there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear - do you mean you want to copy it with a temporary name locally? Or, do you mean you want to rename it on the remote server before copying?

If the former, use the `localFilenameGeneratorExpression`.

If the latter, you would have to use the MV gateway first.

Comment: My question is that **while** I am streaming the file from the remote directory I want some prefix or suffix to be added in the fileName so that other person knows that this file is getting read.

Comment: There is currently no mechanism to rename a remote file while it is being fetched. Seems like a reasonable suggestion. Feel free to open an issue in GitHub.

Comment: Raised an enhancement https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2955 in GitHub for the same